# Java Spring configuration when to define bean and when new

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have a configuration class and I was wondering should I define bean to each class or create new.

```
@Configuration
public class BookConfig {

  @Bean
  public Read readBook() {
    return new ReadBook(new Operation(), new Library(new Location()));
  }
}
```

OR

```
@Configuration
public class BookConfig {

  @Bean
  public Operation operation() {
    return new Operation();
  }

  @Bean
  public Location location() {
    return new Location();
  }

  @Bean
  public Library library() {
    return new Library(location());
  }

  @Bean
  public Read readBook() {
    return new ReadBook(operation(), library());
  }
}
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: Location, Library and Operation look like they are domain objects. If so, you should not configure them as beans as that does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not intend to use Operation and Location bean any time then you can skip creation of that bean and use new as in the first option.
But if you think that Operation and Location beans would be used later second approach is better. Though I would suggest a slight modification. You do not have to call the methods instead pass the bean itself as method param.

```
@Configuration
public class BookConfig {

  @Bean
  public Operation operation() {
    return new Operation();
  }

  @Bean
  public Location location() {
    return new Location();
  }

  @Bean
  public Library library(Location location) {
    return new Library(location);
  }

  @Bean
  public Read readBook(Location location, Library library) {
    return new ReadBook(location, library);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion to always pass the parameters instead of calling the method. When you refactor the code and split the configuration files, you can do so without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, always remember that anything that is made into a Bean will be managed by the Spring boot context itself. Anything that you declare yourself as "new" will not be managed by spring boot and will be treated as a plain java object.

Beans will be singleton by default and have all the life cycle methods run on them (among other things). During Spring boot context creation at startup, bean dependencies will be resolved and you'll have to design your classes in such a way that there is no circular dependency issue.

If you do a "new" then the scope of those object will be restricted to that particular instance of the class and will be destroyed with the instance once it is garbage collected.